# Why do I get an error when trying to deploy a folder of script files with PSDeploy?

Tags: powershell, deployment

I am currently using [PSDeploy](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDeploy) to deploy my PowerShell script modules to a local PowerShell gallery and it is working great for that. It also works for deploying single files such as my profile.ps1.

Now I am wondering if I can use PSDeploy to deploy other non-PowerShell script files such as my AutoHotkey scripts. For the AHK scripts, the deploy task would only be copying a folder, including script files, from my dev location to a location where I run the scripts.

Unfortunately I keep getting an error while attempting to deploy a folder of script files with PSDeploy.

I created a [simple test project on Github](https://github.com/jesmith01/PSDeployTest) to help toubleshoot the error. Anyone can clone this project locally and run a test like I am if they want to.

My test PSDeploy script looks like this:

```
Deploy FolderTest {
  By FileSystem {
    FromSource '.\deployFolderFrom'
    To '.\deployFolderTo'
  }
}
```

This is how I am running my tests.

```
# I am running my test in 'G:\_temp'
cd G:\_temp

# Clone the test project to your test folder or in my case 'G:\_temp'
git clone https://github.com/jesmith01/PSDeployTest.git

# Change directory to the PSDeployTest folder.
cd .\PSDeployTest\

# Run this command from PSDeployTest folder.
Invoke-PSDeploy -Verbose
```

This is my results with verbose setting turned on, error at the end:

[image: Invoke-Deploy with verbose parameter]

My PowerShell version is 7.2.1 as of running this test:

[image: PowerShell version]

My OS version is Windows 11:

[image: Windows OS version]

I even tested out [this example code from RamblingCookieMonster](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDeploy/blob/master/docs/Example-Filesystem-Deployment-Follow-Along.md)  exactly, without changing anything, and I still get an error:

```
# Source folders and files

mkdir C:\PSDeployFrom
mkdir C:\PSDeployFrom\MyModule
mkdir C:\PSDeployFrom\SomeScripts
mkdir C:\PSDeployFrom\Deployments
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\PSDeployFrom\MyModule\MyModule.psm1
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\PSDeployFrom\MyModule\MyModule.psd1
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\PSDeployFrom\SomeScripts\Script1.ps1
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\PSDeployFrom\SomeScripts\Script2.ps1

# Target folder, with a file that mirror should overwrite

mkdir C:\PSDeployTo
mkdir C:\PSDeployTo\MyModule
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\PSDeployTo\MyModule\Remnant.ps1

# Sample PSDeploy.ps1 file

Set-Content C:\PSDeployFrom\Deployments\my.psdeploy.ps1 -Value @'

Deploy ExampleDeployment {

By FileSystem Scripts {

    FromSource 'SomeScripts'
    To 'C:\PSDeployTo'
    Tagged Dev
    DependingOn ExampleDeployment-Modules
}

By FileSystem Modules {

    FromSource MyModule
    To C:\PSDeployTo
    Tagged Prod, Module
    WithOptions @{
        Mirror = $true
    }
}
}
'@

Set-Location -Path 'C:\PSDeployFrom'
```

After running the above sample code:

```
# Run this command from 'C:\PSDeployFrom' folder.
Invoke-PSDeploy -Verbose
```

This is my results with verbose setting turned on, getting the same error at the end:

[image: Deploy sample error]

I reviewed a bunch of *.psdeploy.ps1 scripts from others on GitHub, read the documentation, tested out examples from RamblingCookieMonster, tried using absolute paths, relative paths and I even took a peek at the [PSDeploy source code where I am getting the error](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDeploy/blob/master/PSDeploy/Private/Invoke-Robocopy.ps1). I still cannot figure out where this error is coming from. It appears what I am doing is right.

Q: Is PSDeploy only intended for deploying PowerShell script modules or can it also be used to deploy non-PowerShell folders and files?

Q: Is it possible my PSDeploy installation is faulty or maybe it is not compatible with PowerShell 7.2.1?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @MathiasR.Jessen comment, he gave me the idea to try the same tests with Windows PowerShell 5.1 and they all worked! For now I can just use Windows PowerShell for deployment until I figure out what is broken with PowerShell 7.2.1.

Works with Windows PowerShell 5.1

[image]

Comment: The `System.Reflection.Emit` API that's failing changed between .NET Framework 4.x and .NET 6 - perhaps `PSDeploy` is only meant to work with Windows PowerShell?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You gave me the idea to try the same tests with Windows PowerShell 5.1 and they all worked! For now I can just use Windows PowerShell for deployment until I figure out what is broken with PowerShell 7.2.1. Still not sure if PSDeploy is only intended for Windows PowerShell or not. Thanks!